# Facing Issue while entering value in textbox using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

It might be repeated question but i am facing this issue and not able get any resolution on that.
**Actual Problem:**
    I have to enter same number in two text box using selenium web driver c#. I have tried below code to enter randomly generated number into that text box.On some machine that code is working perfect but on some virtual machine i am not able to enter number as it's loosing focus or something is happening there. 
    So When I run the code sometime it enters value in first text box and sometimes it enters value in second text box.
1st Try: //Not working facing same issue with below code

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(number);
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB}");
Keyboard.SendKeys(number);
```

2nd Try: //Not working facing same issue with below code

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("FirstTextBoxId").SendKeys(number);
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB}");
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("SecondTextBoxId").SendKeys(number);
```

3rd Try: //Not working facing same issue with below code
Used JavaScript to enter value 
4th Try: //Not working facing same issue with below code
Used Auto It tool to enter value
5th Try: //Not working facing same issue with below code
Tried with WAITING and then entering
6th Try: //Not working facing same issue with below code
1st clicked in 1st text box

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("FIRSTTextBoxId").SendKeys(number);
Clicked into second text box
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("SecondTextBoxId").SendKeys(number);
```

In this when i click into that text box then sometimes cursor got set at the middle hence full number is not getting entered i.e. its skipping some value and half number is entered.

**Note:** This two text boxes are located on frame and i am able to switch to frame successfully. I am facing this issue on virtual machine only.
If you look into the attached snapshot then you might get that text box control.
[image]

thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems like that and my solution is: First click on element tben clear it.
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("SecondTextBoxId").click()
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("SecondTextBoxId").clear()

Comment: I have tried same thing but sometime it is working ..no guarantee that all time it will work.